# ReactDOM is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

There is task for me, It`s a website, and we can insert only one JS_SCRIPT in HTML.
So is there any way to make it happen?
I want add scripts by document.createElement. But it did not work.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>
        
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
           
    <script src="./build/test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

./build/test.js

```js
var app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = 'root';

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(app);

(function() {
  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "https://unpkg.com/react@16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
})();

(function() {
  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
})();

(function() {
  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "./build/jsx.bundle.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
})();
```

./build/jsx.bundle.js

```js
'use strict';

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
    'h1',
    null,
    'hello wolrd'
), document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Is there any keyword to search?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you expand a little "is not working"? Do you get a traceback error?
Your way to go seems legit

Comment: Why not do it with create react app and by this manual way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a bundler library like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/). This will generate only one js file for your React app that includes all the libraries, code, css, etc and then you can import it into your website's html. At the end you will end up with only one file called (for example) `bundle.js` (that already includes the react-dom and react scripts) and you can import it like this into your html:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

So there is no need to generate your own js that includes everything like the `test.js` script you have. Using these bundlers have other benefits as well, like minifying, and some other transformations for old browsers as well.

Note: Using webpack is not simple, have a look at the official docs and [this tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/react-webpack-babel/) is easy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Might be not the best solution but gets the job done.

```
document.write('<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: Side note: `document.write` is considered harmful and should not be used

Answer (score 0):

You can always use require.js to bundle all your javscript files into one big javascript file

I think you need to include 2 script tags to create one minute app wit no building tools as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/faa67b76a6c47adbab04f739cba7ceda) by Dan abramov

And it does works with your code see the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9j81qn9q4r) while inserting only one JS_SCRIPT in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Update:Webpack is fine!

---

/*
I got the answer, should change ./build.js, this work fine for me. */

```js
var app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = 'root';

document.querySelector('body').appendChild(app);

(function() {
  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "https://unpkg.com/react@16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
})();

(function() {
  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);

})();
// changed here
window.onload = function() {

  var hm = document.createElement("script");
  hm.src = "./build/jsx.bundle.js";
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(hm, s);
}
```